# fetch API to get ReadableStream

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I was trying to get reader of ReadableStream using `getReader()` and `response.body` of fetch.

Even when I am not consuming data by calling read method, the buffer of stream is getting filled and it is even not applying any kind of backpressure and this is leading to huge memory usage. Is there  any way to set WaterMark size on the `ReadableStream` returned by fetch. Is there any other way to control the buffer size of stream.

Comment: I'm not sure that the problem originated from `read()` method has anything to do with `fetch-api`.. any chance to post some code to clarify your situation?

Comment: What I am trying to ask is even when there are no consumers of stream,the buffer is getting filled and memory consumption is getting high but still, the backpressure is not working. Does the backpressure works over the network streams. Thanks